# Rotating coordinates to wind direction

Tags: r, gaussian

I'm coding a dispersion model using  Gaussian equation but to use it, I have to rotate the coordinates of each grid point (receptors) and to orient them downwind (v, theta) from the source point and then use the equation below:

```
gpm2 = function (x, y) {
conc = qs / (pi * sigmay (x) * sigmaz (x) * ubar) * exp (-1 * (y * y / (2. * sigmay (x) sigmay )) + hg*hg / (2. * sigmaz (x) * sigmaz (x)))) 
return (conc)}
```

I got a file with sources (stacks), lat/long positions and the pollutants emissions:

Source; Area ID;PM;FatEst. MP10_Mptotal;PM10;BTEX;CO;NOx;VOC;SOx
Transportador_de_Sinter;AF01;4.88;0.32;1.56;0;0;0;0;0
Minerio_de_ferro_Transportador_de_cal;AF02;1.95;0.32;0.62;0;0;0;0;0
Transportador_de_carvao_pulverizado;AF03;8.2;0.32;2.62;0;0;0;0;0
Deposito_de_carvao_pulverizado_temp.;AF04;6.45;0.32;2.06;0;0;0;0;0
Carregamento_do_Forno;AF05;66.49;0.32;21.28;0;0;0;0;0
Chamine_Regeneradores;AF06;6.65;0.32;2.13;0;422.57;812.64;20.88;7.24
Limpeza_dos_Gases;AF07;2.22;0.32;0.71;0;0;0;0;0

And another file with observed meteorological data with wind direction (º to North) and speed (m/s)m with air quality data:

date;hour;wd;temp;ru;ws;so2;no2;hcnm;hctot;ch4;co;no;ox;nox;o3;pm10;pmtot
1/1/16;0:30;162.8;24.1;77.0;1.6;14.0;3.2;173.5;2252.3;2078.8;229.6;0.6;0.05;3.7;12.6;21.7;18.5 1/1/16;1:30;166.1;23.5;78.2;1.4;13.8;3.4;188.9;2278.8;2089.9;279.8;0.7;0.04;4.1;11.6;20.3;22.0 1/1/16;2:30;163.0;22.8;81.7;1.6;14.3;3.8;221.7;2339.9;2118.2;334.3;0.7;0.10;4.5;7.7;32.2;33.5 1/1/16;3:30;162.7;22.2;83.5;1.6;14.5;5.0;271.7;2443.2;2171.5;428.0;0.9;0.01;5.9;5.8;42.5;45.6 1/1/16;4:30;162.1;21.8;85.0;1.7;13.4;5.3;271.9;2512.1;2240.2;475.3;1.0;0.02;6.3;4.2;45.0;45.2 1/1/16;5:30;165.7;21.7;85.4;1.9;13.1;5.3;279.9;2571.8;2291.9;477.3;2.1;0.04;7.4;3.5;41.6;41.3 1/1/16;6:30;160.2;21.9;84.9;1.5;15.0;5.3;269.7;2605.9;2336.2;459.8;2.9;0.04;8.3;3.7;40.4;37.9 1/1/16;7:30;150.8;23.8;79.1;1.0;14.0;5.5;273.1;2738.3;2465.2;397.0;6.4;0.08;11.9;4.3;34.2;37.2

My task is to calculate the dispersion for each point of the grid (around 10km x 10km) for each stack, considering the predominant wind direction/speed.

I saw this in some R example, but I don't know how to apply it to each point.

```
x_rot <- xcos (theta) - ysin (theta) 
y_rot <- xsin (theta) + ycon (theta)
```

In my case the sources (stacks) are not at the origin (0,0). 
Do I have to first locate the origin where the source is? How do I do this translation / rotation for each point of the grid?

Thanks !!

Comment: Please do not cross post, you've ask this question to [SO in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237797/transforma%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-coordenadas-de-vento-para-equa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-gaussiana) 1 hour ago.

Comment: add a small example of the grid you're working with

Comment: Rui, I did because I've realized I could reach more people in English, than I deleted it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Rawr, just put it in my post! Thanks!